# Play browser audio, with screen off [BQ M10 ]

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, m10

Is there a way to turn off the screen but leave audio in the browser playing to save battery?

I'm using Ubuntu Touch on a BQ M10

Comment: I don,t think so. But you could reduce the brighness to its minimum.;)

Comment: Already did that...